# Unix: Get the latest entry from the file

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file where there are name and time. I want to keep the entry only with the latest time. How do I do it?

for example:

```
>cat user.txt
"a","03-May-13
"b","13-May-13
"a","13-Aug-13
"a","13-May-13
```

I am using command `sort -u user.txt`. It is giving the following output:

```
"a","11-May-13
"a","13-Aug-13
"a","13-May-13
"b","13-May-13
```

but I want the following output.

```
"a","13-Aug-13
"b","13-May-13
```

Can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean "a","13-May-13", or did you intend to leave off the trailing '"'?

Comment: Additionally, do you want the first field, or *only* the date?

Comment: @Arafangion I intentionally left the trailing quote. And I want both the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to sort year, month and day.

Can you try this

```
awk -F"\"" '{print $2"-"$4}' data.txt | sort -t- -k4 -k3M -k2 | awk -F- '{kv[$1]=$2"-"$3"-"$4}END{for(k in kv){print k,kv[k]}}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sort -t, -k2 user.txt | awk -F, '{a[$1]=$2}END{for(e in a){print e, a[e]}}' OFS=","
```

Explanation:

Sort the entries by the date field in ascending order, pipe the sorted result to awk, which simply uses the first field as a key, so only the last entry of the entries with an identical key will be kept and finally output.

**EDIT**

Okay, so I can't sort the entries lexicographically. the date need to be converted to timestamp so it can be compared numerically, use the following:

```
awk -F",\"" '{ cmd=" date --date " $2 " +%s "; cmd | getline ts; close(cmd); print ts, $0, $2}' user.txt | sort -k1 | awk -F"[, ]" '{a[$2]=$3}END{for(e in a){print e, a[e]}}' OFS=","
```

If you are using MacOS, use `gdate` instead:

```
awk -F",\"" '{ cmd=" gdate --date " $2 " +%s "; cmd | getline ts; close(cmd); print ts, $0, $2}' user.txt | sort -k1 | awk -F"[, ]" '{a[$2]=$3}END{for(e in a){print e, a[e]}}' OFS=","
```

Comment: Missed that '-k2' option there, that does simplify the answer somewhat!

Comment: Thanks @neevek . Your solution is good but it has issues. It looks to be doing lexicographic comparison. It fails for the following test case. `"a","3-May-13
"b","13-May-13
"a","11-May-13
"a","13-May-13`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
grep `cut -d'"' -f4 user.txt | sort -t- -k 3 -k 2M -k 1n | tail -1` user.txt
```

Explaining: using sort as you have done, get the latest entry with tail -1, extract that date (second column when cutting with a comma delimiter) and then sort and grep on that.

edit: fixed to sort via month.

Comment: @RachitAgrawal i modified the sort to work with month, does this work for you now?

Answer (score 0):

For me this is doing the job. I am sorting on the Month and then applying the logic that @neevek used. Till now I am unable to find a case that fails this. But I am not sure if this is a full proof solution.

```
sort -t- -k2 -M user1.txt | awk -F, '{a[$1]=$2}END{for(e in a){print e, a[e]}}' OFS=","
```

Can someone tell me if this solution has any issues?